# get method as parameter

Tags: c#, delegates

I am new to C# .

I want to review an element, for that I have a Reviewer class and a Checklist (static) class.

I wish to have a function Reviewer Validate(element).

This function should get the review logics from checklist (in the form of a delegate or other means) and review the element by just using the element on that logic.

Because physically checklists have only logics and reviewer(person) uses those logics on the element

Note:I don't want the reviewer to call a function in Checklist class to validate the element.

Is this possible in C#?

i need something like below.

```
static class Checklist
{
}

static class Reviewer
{
public Result Valiadate(Element element)
{
////i want to do here wat is linq doing internally 
//// i.e lync gets the logic from us , performs it on the object.
/// similarly i have the object here as element , need to get logic from checklist and review the element using it.
}
}

Class Client
{
void Validate(Element element)
{
Reviewer.Validate(element);
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible in C#. So, after answering your question, what is your actual problem?

Comment: I need to implement it. How shall i do it?

Comment: You do it my opening Visual Studio, writing code, and compiling it. If you want a more detailed instruction of how to do something you will need to give a more detailed question explaining what is keeping you from writing this yourself.

Comment: Use a delegate... For example, let's say checklist has a method `public static void DoSomething(Element e)`. Then you can create a delegate of this method like `Action<Element> delegateDoSomething = checklist.DoSomething;` That's the best and *only* suggestion i can give, based on the very little -almost nonexistant- information you have given...

Comment: Added more info in the question

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I don't understand. there are many Element types? if there are many types of elements any review will do the same (for example: if(element.X > 0) return true  else return false;)? Or maybe every element will have diferent logic? How can you get logic or delegate from checklist without call that class?...What are you trying to do?

Comment: If the Reviewer is actually static then that means the only way this is possible is if the element has a reference back to its checklist and that would mean you shouldn't use an object. In order to truly determine if this is possible we'd actually need to know what the element class is.

Comment: Element class just contains properties each of which is set to certain value. The Checklist should have logics to check it against specified values. This is crisply wat the element class is.

Comment: I just made the reviewer class static because i need only one instance of it. no more reasons. it can also be kept non static.

Comment: That is a bad reason to make a class static. If you only need one instance of it then only instantiate one instance of it. Do not make it static.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems very strange. Do you want something like this?

```
public static class Checklist
{
    public static List<Reviewer> Reviewers { get; private set; }

    public static bool Validate(object element)
    {
        return true;
    }

    static Checklist()
    {
        Reviewers = new List<Reviewer>();
        Reviewers.Add(new Reviewer((elem)=>true));
    }
}

public class Reviewer
{
    private Func<object, bool> _itsValidator;

    public Reviewer(Func<object,bool> validator)
    {
        _itsValidator = validator;
    }

    public bool Validate(object element)
    {
        return _itsValidator(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: I really think that this is a good solution, the only thing I see potentially wrong with it is that his reviewer is static. It also uses this element class. If the Reviewer is actually static then that means the only way this is possible is if the element has a reference back to its checklist and that would mean you shouldn't use an object. In order to truly determine if this is possible we'd actually need to know what the element class is.

Comment: @Aelphaeis Well, my code was written when OP didn't provide any sources.. In code, OP gave us, i don't see any possibility to inject method from CheckList instead of using DI container, which i find drastically bad. Anyway, i don't see any reason he can't call Checklist method from Reviewer if he needs it's logic

Comment: I can't see the reason either, you're quite right when you say that the question is very strange. Regardless, good solution. +1.